# Loading Data with column Headers

Tags: data, orange

I have a file called adult.data that contains my test set in a CSV file format.  Unfortunately there are no column headers in the file to describe the variables.  But I have a file called adult.names that contains a description of the different variables.

How can I add the column headers from the adult.names file so after loading the  adult.data file in Orange I can see the data along with the header names in a Data Table?

Answer (score 1):

I have three answers:

1. it is not directly possible (I guess, copying the labels from the one file into the csv file doesn't count, no?!)
2. Well, it *is* possible but I doubt that it's worth the effort: you
   can use the python scripting functionality and connect the Python
   script to the scv file and the "label" file. There is some info here:
   https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/data/pythonscript.html
3. you can create a new widget that let's you choose the csv file and the label file (this requires even more Python coding than 2.). A good starting point is this: https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-development/en/latest/tutorial.html

Orange is, in my experience, really cool as long as your use case exist already. However, more serious extension of the functionality is not that easy.